# Remove image extension using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to remove from img scr extension using jQuery?

meaning from this:

```
<img src="images/6208606.jpg" width="120" height="120" />
```

to this:

```
<img src="images/6208606" width="120" height="120" />
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
$('img').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace(/\.jpg/, ''));
});
```

If you have multiple extensions you need to look for you could do:

```
var exts = ['.jpg', '.gif', '.png'];
$('img').each(function(){
    var $t = $(this);
    $.each(exts, function(i,v){
        $t.attr('src', $t.attr('src').replace(v, ''));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to provide some identification (like id, name, alt) or specific class to select image using jquery selector.

```
//using css class 'special' applied to images whose
//src we need to replace
var i=$('img.special');
var s = $(i).attr("src");
s = s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf("."));
$(i).attr("src",s);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Find the image using jQuery
2. Get it's "src" property
3. Modify it as a simple string
4. Assign it back to "src"