# jQuery append img src

Tags: jquery

How can I add "_small.jpg" to the img src of a bunch of images I have in a div called "banners"?

I have a jQuery script listening for window resizes - and when below 400px I want to change the img src of the images to include "_small.jpg" at the end to call in the small image source. So...

```
<img src="example.jpg" />
```

when viewed at screen sizes below 480px would then become

```
<img src="example_small.jpg" />
```

How would I do this?

P.S. I'd like the script to loop through all the images in the "banners" div to update them btw :)

Comment: I think this is not a nice move, because if you have the src set to example.jpg in your html, those images will be loaded anyway and then replaced when you add the _small string. I would either leave the src empty and load all the images with js (depending on the screen size) or set the size of the images in your css.

Comment: Instead keep one image and give max-width:100%

Comment: I want to load a different image with different aspect ratio for small use cases on the carousel - hence the question - keeping the same source at 100% is easy - but means you have a carousel which looks nice on desktop and crap on mobile if you use the same img src scaled to the width whilst maintaining aspect ratio :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try:

```
// define this somewhere in your code (credit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280634/endswith-in-javascript)
function endsWith(str, suffix) {
    return str.indexOf(suffix, str.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
}

if ($(window).width() < 480) {
  $("div.banners img").each(function() {
    if (!endsWith($(this).attr('src'), '_small.jpg')) {
      // if you have more than "jpg" files you will want to replace those as well
      $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace(/\.jpg/, '') + '_small.jpg');
    }
  });
}
```

I believe that should do it!

**Edit** - Added an extension remove based on a comment. For more information on replacing extensions see [this stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550244/remove-image-extension-using-jquery).

**Edit 2** - Added a check for "endswith" in case the function is called on items that already have the small extension added!.

Comment: @isherwood You are correct! I think that should do it now.

Comment: @dubbs Should be fixed. Sorry about that!

Comment: done. a nice solution, but the issue here is when using this on a fluid responsive approach, i am testing to check the window size on any change to the browser size which then re-does this script - therefore adds _small.jpg again... which breaks it... any way of only making it add _small.jpg if not already done so?

Comment: @dubbs I added a function call to "endsWith" to make sure that the image source doesn't have "_small.jpg" already. Best of luck!

Comment: @drew_w - thanks - but that doesnt seem to work... on resize, the script is still firing and adding _small to the JPEGs...

Comment: @dubbs This should be really close. There could be an issue with upper versus lower case or something along those lines. Debug using your browser tools and I think you should be able to figure it out from there. Happy hunting!

Comment: @drew_w - hmmm... something not right... any chance of a jfiddle example of it working?

Comment: @drew_w - found it....  if (!endsWidth($(this).attr('src'), '_small.jpg')) { ... should be  if (!endsWith($(this).attr('src'), '_small.jpg')) {

Comment: @dubbs My bad! Have fixed the answer. Feel free to mark as correct if it works : )

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$("div.banners img").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", function() {
        var src = this.src.split(".")[0];
        return src + "_small.jpg";
    });
});
```

(The above assumes image names have no "." in them and all have a type of JPEG)

Comment: You don't need to iterate through the images, `$('div.banners img').attr` should be enough http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/SrH8X/

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
var src = $('img').attr('src'),
    ext = src.substr( src.lastIndexOf('.') );

src = src.replace(ext, '_small' + ext, src);

$('img').attr('src', src);
```

Or with regex:

```
var src = $('img').attr('src'),
    src = src.replace(/(\..*)$/, '_small$1', src);

$('img').attr('src', src);
```