# Toggle img src file path

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
<div class="flex-gametypes">
    <div><img src="assets/images/game/one.png"></div>
    <div><img src="assets/images/game/two.png"></div>
</div>
```

I have the following image files:

```
assets/images/game/one.png
assets/images/game/two.png
assets/images/game/one-highlight.png
assets/images/game/two-highlight.png
```

**What I want to do:**

When I click on one.png, the code must rename the file to one-highlight.png.

When I click on it (one.png) again, it should continue to be one-highlight.png.

But if I were to click on two.png, then one-highlight.png should be back as one.png and two.png should now be two-highlight.png

So, this is **what I tried**: (I got some help from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22304608/jquery-append-img-src?rq=1)).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".flex-gametypes img").click(function(){
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('-hightlight.png') + '');
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace(/\.png/, '') + '-highlight.png');
    });
});
```

But this does not display the desired result. So how can I achieve this effect?

Comment: It's not displaying the desirable result because you are doing two replacements back-to-back: that's not a toggle logic you're looking for

Comment: Hmm, the reason I wanted that was because I want to reset it each time it is clicked.

Comment: You will need to store the toggled binary state somewhere: how would your element know which state it is in?

Comment: And I used the wrong word, its not toggle.  What I want is like when an image is clicked, an image specific to it gets loaded. When its clicked again, then nothing happens. But if a different image is clicked, then the previously adjusted image goes back to the initial stage and the newly click image gets a new image.

Comment: Ok I've edited the question so it is more clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my example I used `indexOf()`. Now it works the way you wanted. By the toggle principle.

```js
$(".flex-gametypes img").each(function() {
  $(this).click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('src').indexOf('-highlight.png') != -1) {
      $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace(/\-highlight.png/, '') + '.png') 
    } else {
      $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace(/\.png/, '') + '-highlight.png')
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex-gametypes">
    <div><img src="assets/images/game/one.png"></div>
    <div><img src="assets/images/game/two.png"></div>
    <div><img src="assets/images/game/one-highlight.png"></div>
    <div><img src="assets/images/game/two-highlight.png"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".flex-gametypes div img").click(function(){
        $(".flex-gametypes div img").each(function(){
            $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('-highlight', ''));
        });
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace(/\.png/, '') + '-highlight.png');
        
    });
});
```

When ever an image clicked the function removes every -highlight from every image and then adds the -hightlight only to the image that got clicked.

I hope this works for you.

Comment: hi, this gives me error. If I click on the image , it does add the "-highlight.png". But if I click on it again, the file name becomes "one-highlight-highlight.png".

Comment: sorry mate, had a typo on the first replacement on word `highlight`. I edited the code so it should work as expected

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your jQuery with this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".flex-gametypes img").click(function(){
        $(".flex-gametypes img").each(function(){
            $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('-highlight.png', '.png'));
        });
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('.png', '-highlight.png'));
        
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex-gametypes">
  <div><img src="assets/images/game/one.png"></div>
  <div><img src="assets/images/game/two.png"></div>
</div>
```

I just fixed a typo and changed the replacement code. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: When I click on another image, the previously clicked image is still highlighted.

Comment: @Gosi, sorry, I didn't see that part. Try my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

First it will change all the highlighted with normal then highlights the current image clicked, hope it helps

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".flex-gametypes img").on('click',function() {
    $(".flex-gametypes img").each(function(i,obj){
          $(obj).attr('src', $(obj).attr('src').replace('-highlight.png', '.png'));
    })
      $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('.png', '-highlight.png'));
  });});
```