# Changing image suffix with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to change image suffix for all image having class "thumb". They can be in jpg, png or gif

```
<img class="thumb" src="http://someting.com/images/abc-150X150.jpg"/>
```

Want to remove **-150X150**

```
<img class="thumb" src="http://someting.com/images/abc.jpg"/>
```

I've come to know [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1550272/3070446), But it removes extensions and uses img tag instead of class. Thanks for watching my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
$('img.thumb').each(function() {
  this.src = this.src.replace('-150X150', '');
});
```

Comment: I tested it worked. And upvoted, don't know who downvoted. I was thinking about both @carl-markham  and your answer. I think using regex will be slower it because it will be checking before replacing. I should use your method when suffix is same in all images. Is it?

Comment: Well, I don't think the difference in speed is really worth talking. What is, however, is that with string replace your target is clear - it's ONLY this '-150X150' line, nothing more. With regex, it's not so: consider what happens with `'pic_of_4x4_car-150x150.jpg'`, for example.

Comment: If it will always be 150x150 then this is the best answer. If it changes sometimes then you will need regex

Answer (score 2):

This uses regex to replace and pattern that matches a hyphen, followed by a digit, then an X and another digit

```
$('.thumb').attr('src', function (index, src) { 
    return src.replace(/-\d+x\d+/, ''); 
});
```

It is worth noting that this is just simple regex. If you wanted to get more complex then you could specify a minimum number of integers either side of the **x** to reduce matching the wrong thing, such as:

`/-\d{3,}x\d{3,}/`

The above will match 3 or more digits either side of the **x**

Comment: I'd recommend using the callback of `attr()`, rather than calling it twice: `attr('src', function(index, oldSRC){ return oldSRC.replace(/* regex */,''); });` (or using `prop()` instead, but that's a personal preference).

Comment: Regex is good for varring suffixes. It didn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/waqasss/n2uA5/1/

Comment: That is because you are using an uppercase X in your question (so I added an uppercase X to the regex), but you are using a lowercase x in the fiddle. I've changed the answer and fiddle

Comment: I added some more information to the answer regarding the possibility of matching the wrong thing as mentioned in @raina77ow's comment

Comment: Well, the safer approach would be to replace the prefix only if it precedes an extension - by adding `(?=\.[^.]+$)` to it, for example. While that'll make this path more universal, I honestly doubt such a complexity is useful for this particular task. Still, I can be wrong. )